# Swift Sprite Kit passing Bool

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I got a Image with 2 faces, Up and Down ( Imagine a Card ).
Whenever you tap the Image, it changes it image.

I used a `Bool` to get the expression. However, after the Scene is presented again, I want to show the image which was Up/Down in the last Scene. Note that this is only 1 Scene, and it presents itself again.

How can I pass a `Bool` value between the Scene?

//Update:

My Code:

```
....
var FaceUp = true
.... 

override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

TTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "TCard.png")
TTexture.filteringMode = .Nearest
T2Texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "T2Card.png")
T2Texture.filteringMode = .Nearest

Card = SKSpriteNode(texture: TTexture)
Card.position = CGPoint(x: Rate.position.x - (TransparentLayer.size.width / 3), y: Rate.position.y)
Card.size = CGSize(width: 50, height: 50)
Card.name = "Card"
Card.zPosition = 100
self.addChild(Card)

flip(FaceUp)

}

func flip(state : Bool) {
    FaceUp = state
    if (!state) {
        Card.texture = TTexture //Error
        Player.texture = T1
        Player.runAction(RunAnimation1)
        FaceUp = true
    } else {
        Card.texture = T2Texture //Error
        Player.texture = T2
        Player.runAction(RunAnimation2)
        FaceUp = false
    }
}

override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {

    let touch:UITouch = touches.anyObject() as UITouch
    let touchLocation = touch.locationInNode(self)

    let Node:SKNode = self.nodeAtPoint(touchLocation)

    if Node.name == "Card" {

        let Scale1 = SKAction.scaleTo(0.7, duration: 0.1)
        let Scale2 = SKAction.scaleTo(1, duration: 0.1)
        let Scaling = SKAction.sequence([Scale1, Scale2])
        Card.runAction(Scaling)

        self.flip(FaceUp)

}
}

func Restart(){

    self.saveHighScore()

    LastScore = Score
    self.addLeaderboardScore(self.Score)
    let Transition = SKTransition.fadeWithDuration(1.8)
    let Scene = GameScene(size: self.frame.size)
    Scene.LastScore = Score
    Scene.FaceUp = FaceUp
    scene?.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleMode.AspectFill

    self.scene?.view?.presentScene(Scene, transition: Transition)

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a function in `GameScene` like the following.

```
func setCardState(state : Bool) {
    FaceUp = state
    if (!state) {
        Card.texture = Texture2
        Player.texture = T2
    } else {
        Card.texture = Texture1
        Player.texture = T1
    }
}
```

And call it from `didMoveToView` in the new scene.

```
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

    TTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "TCard.png")
    TTexture.filteringMode = .Nearest
    T2Texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "T2Card.png")
    T2Texture.filteringMode = .Nearest

    Card = SKSpriteNode(texture: TTexture)
    Card.position = CGPoint(x: Rate.position.x -  (TransparentLayer.size.width / 3), y: Rate.position.y)
    Card.size = CGSize(width: 50, height: 50)
    Card.name = "Card"
    Card.zPosition = 100
    self.addChild(Card)

    setCardState(FaceUp) // added line.

}
```

Also set the old `FaceUp` value in the new scene in `Restart function`.

```
func Restart(){

    self.saveHighScore()

    LastScore = Score
    self.addLeaderboardScore(self.Score)
    let Transition = SKTransition.fadeWithDuration(1.8)
    let Scene = GameScene(size: self.frame.size)
    Scene.LastScore = Score
    scene?.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleMode.AspectFill

    Scene.FaceUp = FaceUp //changed line.  

    self.scene?.view?.presentScene(Scene, transition: Transition)

}
```

Comment: I got it working with changing the Image texture with your method, however after the new scene should be presented, it gives me `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value` in the `setCardState` function

Comment: can you show your new code? where are you getting the error?

Comment: where are you loading the textures?

Comment: Thank you very much for taking your time! 
The Error is now gone, but after the scene restarts itself, the wrong Image is shown ( it`s again FaceUp = true, although it should be FaceUp = false).

Comment: did u add the new line in `didMoveToView`?

Comment: Yes, I got the exact same Code as you suggested.

Comment: and did u change the line in Restart too?

Comment: don't call flip. doesn't flip change the state again. In my answer I have mentioned to create a new function `setCardState`. call `setCardState` from didMoveToView to set the previous state

Comment: calling flip will flip the state again from the previous state

Comment: I simply misunderstood you. I thought instead of Flip I should change it into setCardState, but you meant I should add this as a new function.
Now it works! Thank you very much and sorry for taking it so long!